# How to do ASP.NET Core controllers avaiable using Screaming Architecture Conventions?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, architecture, asp.net-core-webapi, clean-architecture

I'm trying to understand how to do an Asp.Net Core application (3.0) looks like a Screaming Architecture folders and files conventions.

I read about it but and started with an empty project. The folders are:

- Controllers
- Views
- Models

I want to make the web application working like

- Customers/Controllers
- Customers/Views
- Customers/Models

Is it possible?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Both controllers and models are referenced by namespace, so their physical file locations have no bearing on anything. Controllers are dynamically loaded regardless of where they are in the project or even if they're in the project at all (i.e. a controller from a referenced library will automatically be loaded). Models are entirely code-based, and you'd just add a using statement with the namespace of the model(s) to access them in any other piece of code.

Views, however, are very much based on the filesystem, and changing the main folder they're in from just `Views` or `Pages` directly in the project root will cause the convention-based view loading to fail completely. You can always add additional view search locations, such that it will look in `/Foo/Views` and `/Bar/Views`, etc. but that's really not recommended.

All that said, though, there is a concept of areas, and you *can* break down your controllers, models, *and* views that way. You'd simply have to have:

- Areas/Customers/Controllers
- Areas/Customers/Views
- Areas/Customers/Models

In other words, the `Areas` prefix would be mandatory.

Comment: Thanks Chris for your comment! I already knew about the areas concept but I don't think it's for the purpose I'm trying to. Did you read about Screaming architecture? I understand about the convention stuff, but I really want to try the it inside a asp.net mvc project. My main goal really is apply this pattern of folders and file names on it's structure. Thanks anyway for your help

Comment: Following conventions by either keeping the main `Views` folder or using `Areas` *would be* "screaming architecture", in that sense that anyone familiar with ASP.NET Core knows exactly what this is, what it does, and where to look for things. Ironically, moving stuff around to create a "screaming architecture", would defeat the purpose, as any ASP.NET Core developer would be lost trying to find a view, for example.